# pnmixer doesn't work after installing pavucontrol

Tags: audio, alsa

I'm using Manjaro Openbox and I tried to set up my microphone after the [arch wiki](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/PulseAudio/Troubleshooting#Microphone_not_detected_by_PulseAudio)
I just changed in /etc/pulse/default.pa

```
load-module module-alsa-source device=hw:0,0
# the line above should be somewhere before the line below
.ifexists module-udev-detect.so
```

Then my audio output didn't worked at all, I installed pavucontrol and I was able to change the output device for every single application (obviously the default output device did changed somehow).

But since then, my pnmixer doesn't affect the volume anymore and I need to change the volume level in pavucontrol.

But the pnmixer still affects the output of 'amixer'

`Simple mixer control 'Master',0
  Capabilities: pvolume pswitch pswitch-joined
  Playback channels: Front Left - Front Right
  Limits: Playback 0 - 65536
  Mono:
  Front Left: Playback 44564 [68%] [on]
  Front Right: Playback 44564 [68%] [on]
Simple mixer control 'Capture',0
  Capabilities: cvolume cswitch cswitch-joined
  Capture channels: Front Left - Front Right
  Limits: Capture 0 - 65536
  Front Left: Capture 41350 [63%] [on]
  Front Right: Capture 41350 [63%] [on]`

But it doesn't change the actual output sound level. And uninstalling pavucontrol didn't brought back the functionality of pnmixer

since the audio stack of linux is so confusing I've no idea what happened. If you need more information, I'll be happy to provide it

Thanks in advance

Comment: I solved this problem by playing back a backup. Lucky I, I just created one 2 days before I messed up my config.